# A projectile with huge initial speed

Tags: kinematics, projectile

in a **projectile**, if the value of **initial speed is very large**, 2000 m/sec for example, and the **shooting angle is not equal to 0** degrees
why would the rules of the maximal height and range (maximal horizontal distance): [image]
hmax=(vo*sinα)²/2g & R=(vo²sin2α)/g
where g=9.8 m/s2
vo: initial speed (2000 for example)
α: shooting angle

I know that it has a rectilinear trajectory initially but I failed to find a method to prove it

Comment: Hello! It is preferable to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: It's not comletely clear what you're asking. Did you accidentally leave a word or two out of your question?

Comment: BTW, those equations are a simplification. They ignore air resistance, and are only applicable in a small region, where the curvature of  the Earth, its spin, and the variations of *g*, can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If theta is zero, the maximum height would be zero, and the range would be zero. These formula make sense, Not that these formula are assuming the object is initially on the ground